# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("OrderDevice", "ImportXML", FormMethod.Post))
{ %>

<table id="OrderDevices" class="data-table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            DeviceId
        </th>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            OrderId
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>

        <td>
            <input readonly="readonly" class="" id="DeviceId" type="text" 
                name="<%= Html.Encode(item.DeviceId) %>"  
                value="<%= Html.Encode(item.DeviceId) %>" style="width: 61px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input readonly="readonly" class="" id="c" type="text" 
                name= "<%= Html.Encode(item.Id) %>"  value="
    <%= Html.Encode(item.Id) %>" 
                style="width: 50px" />      
        </td>
        <td>
            <input readonly="readonly" class="" id="OrderId" type="text" 
                name= " <%= Html.Encode(item.OrderId) %>"  
                value="<%= Html.Encode(item.OrderId) %> " style="width: 49px" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>

<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
<%} %>
```

My controller action:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult OrderDevice(int id)
    {   
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here        
            orderdevice ord = new orderdevice();
            ord.Id = System.Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Id"]);
            ord.OrderId = System.Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["OrderId"]);
            ord.DeviceId = System.Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["DeviceId"]);

            XMLEntities.AddToorderdevice(ord);
            XMLEntities.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

When post a form I have this error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult OrderDevice(Int32)' in 'MvcKVteam.Controllers.ImportXMLController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

How fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would suggest you use MVC's automatic handling of parameters instead ofpulling them out of the Request yourself.  Your controller action has an id parameter which seems to go ignored - use that and add others like it to get the input parameters.

Secondly, your HTML looks a bit off.  You're using device ID, item ID and order ID *values* as the input element *names*. This will mean that instead of having `deviceId=123&itemId=456&orderId=789` you're getting `123=123&456=456&789=789` which isn't very useful!  Try changing the input fields to something like:

```
<input ... name="deviceId" value="<%= Html.Encode(item.DeviceId) %>" ... />
```

You can then have a parameter caled`deviceId` in your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult OrderDevice(int deviceId, int itmId, int orderId)
{
    // ...
}
```

Doing it this way, you won't ned to use Request.Form[...] yourself at all.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates, the parameter you are sending to the controller from view is not in the same name.

example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.PropertyId, "View", new { @id= item.PropertyId })


public ActionResult Edit(int propId)
{
            var result = _service.GetProperty(propId);
            return View("Index", result);
}
```

In this code the parameter 'id' passed from view. but the actual parameter name is 'propId'. change the name would fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that mvc  canoot find a value for your ID property that must be passed as an argument.To resolve this include the following on your controller.

public  ActionResult  OrderDevice  (string id)
    {

```
         ViewBag.S = id;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            int idint = Convert.ToInt16(id);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here        
        orderdevice ord = new orderdevice();


        XMLEntities.AddToorderdevice(ord.Search(idint));
        XMLEntities.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
            }
        }

        return View();

    }
```

Seacrh is for an assumption that your programme contains a method that searches for a Device.Hope this helps.