# What is wrong with my MVC4 Routes, Parameters, constructors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, routes, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem with a small app i am writing. Now either my error is in my controller class or its in Routes. See images below.

Controller Class.

[image: This is the controller i am trying to execute]

This is the default Route i have.

[image: RouteConfig file]

And this is the error i get when i run.
Image not very clear but it says:

**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'playerId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Detail(Int32)' in 'GlobalUnited.WebUI.Controllers.PlayerController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters**

[image: Error]

I read through some posts on here, one particularly:
[Similar Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863776/the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter)

What exactly does he mean when Daniel Renshaw says:

**First, I would suggest you use MVC's automatic handling of parameters instead ofpulling them out of the Request yourself. Your controller action has an id parameter which seems to go ignored - use that and add others like it to get the input parameters.**

Anyways, after reading that post, i changed my RouteConfig file to:

[image: Changed Route]

And Still i got this error. It says:

**A route named 'DefaultApi' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name**

[image: Route]

I even tried to change my Detail action parameter to: Note the int? declaration
[image: method]

And i got this error after changing:

[image]

Is there something i could do to fix this, something less complicated??
All help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: +1 For using the dark theme. :)

Comment: Please post code as code, not as images.

Comment: Thanks Henk Holterman, i will make sure that i do so the next time

Comment: What is the URL you are using?

Comment: @MystereMan `http://localhost:5169/Player/Detail?PlayerId=1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parameter name playerID causes the problem here. ASP.NET MVC can only provide you a parameter named id using the default route. In your case, it cannot map the request to your action because playerID is not nullable or optional. Changing your parameter name to id will solve the problem.

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
```

You get the second error with route registration because you already have a route named "DefaultApi". You won't need this route if you change the parameter name(also it's registered elsewhere).

Third error is for trying to querying with the null value. ASP.NET MVC cannot map the value in URL to your parameter and you get the default value null. Since there isn't a row with a null value you get an empty sequence, then Single() method throws an exception.

Comment: I did what you suggested, i still get the same nullable error as before. And also i deleted the DefaultApi in RouteConfig. But if i may asked, since yoy said that this route is being registered somewhere else, do you know where its being registered?

Comment: @KomengeMwandila How do you produce your links? What URL gets you the error? The route should be registered in RouteConfig class in default ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

Comment: Haciogullari This is the url i am trying to reach: http://localhost:5169/Player/Detail

Comment: The DefaultApi route is registered in App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: @KomengeMwandila Well the problem is here. You are not providing a value for id parameter. That action will respond to URLs like http://localhost:5169/Player/Detail/5. Since you are using Single() in your action method, I thought it is not legit to use URLs like that.

Comment: Your action method expects an id, so you must enter this URL: localhost:5169/Player/Detail/1

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları sorry this is the url `http://localhost:5169/Player/Detail?PlayerId=1` I am just trying to make this answer work, the above answer by Leniel works at the moment

Comment: @KomengeMwandila you can use URLs like http://localhost:5169/Player/Detail/1 if you use id as parameter name.

Comment: @KomengeMwandila yep, that's the most widely used approach but you are free to choose whatever you like.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Just a quick question, can i mark 2 answers on here? I would like to give both you guys credit but your approach seems to demand less code and no if statement. Which i would assume less execution time.

Comment: @KomengeMwandila You can only mark one of them as accepted answer but you can upvote them all.

Answer (score 1):

As your parameter is called `playerId` you must pass it as a route value to the `Detail` action method and then check if it's null or not. This will take care of that last error you show in your question: *Sequence contains no element*.

Do this in the action method:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int? playerId)
{
   if(playerId.HasValue)
   {
       var model = _dataSource.Players.Single(p => p.PlayerId == playerId);

       return View(model);
   }

   // Handle the other possibility where playerId is NULL
}
```

For ASP.NET MVC to know how to do the correct parameter binding you must call the above action method this way, for example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Player Details", "Detail", new { playerId = 1 });
```

Comment: playerID will always be null because ASP.NET MVC knows nothing about a parameter named playerID.

Comment: This is what i have in the index file that contains links to the Detail file:  ' @Html.ActionLink(player.Name, "Detail", "Player", new {player.PlayerId}, null)'

Comment: Since you're using `id` as the parameter name and not `playerId` on your action method, you must have this: `@Html.ActionLink(player.Name, "Detail", "Player", new { id = player.PlayerId }, null)`. This will make the whole thing work as expected. :)

Comment: @LenielMacaferi - that's not true, using his method it will create a querystring called playerId, which will then bind the value to parameter.  However, it will not use the friendly url and contain a querystring.

Comment: @MystereMan: an action link with an `id` route parameter like what he has in his action method... is that not correct?

Comment: @LenielMacaferi - yes, that can work, but you said he "must" have it.  He doesn't have to, since MVC will just create a querystring parameter instead of using the ID.  It should work either way.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi i got it to work, i didn't have to do what you suggested in that last commet: new { id = player.PlayerId } It worsk with it too though. Bu i don't have to assign playerId = 1

Comment: @KomengeMwandila nice to hear that!

Comment: Let me explore the answer below more. I would like to have options. But i will mark whatever works as answer

Answer (score 1):

Other than the duplicate route error, your errors have nothing to do with the DefaultApi route.  You get a duplicate route because that route is configured in App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs

Your first problem is that you are telling MVC that you have a mandatory Route parameter called playerId, but you are not supplying this route parameter in the URL you're using.  In order for this to work you would need to either alter your route to change id to playerId, or add a playerId querystring parameter to your url.  If you alter the route, you would need a url like `http://my.site/Player/Detail/1` (if you alter the route) or `http://my.site/Player/Detail?playerId=1`.

Another option is changing the parameter to `public ActionResult Detail(int id)` which would then use the existing default route that takes a single parameter called id and extracts it from the friendly url that ends in `/1`.

You could also make the method `Detail(int? id)`, but then you would need to place a null guard around your linq query (because if you don't pass the ID on the URL it can't lookup a null record) so you would have to add this:

```
if (id.HasValue) {
    // execute linq query
}
```

Alternatively, you could alter your query to return `SingleOrDefault()` rather than `Single()`.

Comment: Thanks for your input man, thats pretty much the summary of the 2 answers given below.